# nginx: Redirect all requests to a proxy, but not these three specific URLs

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect, 301-redirect

nginx can be tricky sometimes:

I want to

- redirect all incoming requests for `www.sub.domain.com/*` to `www.other.domain.com/*`
- use a proxy so users still see the original `www.sub.domain.com` when browsing the site
- add an exception for specific URLs (all the same kind): `www.sub.domain.com/script` needs to redirect to `www.yet.another.domain.com/www.sub.domain.com/new_script`, preserving the entered POST data for the script. With the little trickiness that the folder containing `new_script` is named just after the original domain.

Here's what I got so far:

`server {
        listen   xx.xx.xx.xx:80;
        root /var/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name www.sub.domain.com;`

```
    location /cms/ {
            proxy_pass              http://yy.yy.yy.yy:8080;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    }

    location /script {
            proxy_pass              http://www.yet.another.domain.com/www.sub.domain.com/;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;
    }

    location / {
            proxy_pass              http://yy.yy.yy.yy:8080;
            proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header        Host $http_host;

            rewrite ^/int/a.([a-zA-Z]+).([0-9]+)$ /site/int/a?l=$1&i=$2 last;
            rewrite ^(.*)$ /site/$1 last;
    }
```

}

On accessing `www.sub.domain.com/script`, this happens:

`curl -I www.sub.domain.com/script
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.6.0
Date: Mon, 04 Aug 2014 04:12:23 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 184
Location: http://www.sub.domain.com/script/
Connection: keep-alive`

In addition, a 404 error is shown: 
"Not Found: The requested URL /www.sub.domain.com/ was not found on this server."

Where's my mistake? I can't spot it. (Or is it a bunch of mistakes? I'm quite new to nginx redirects.)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The second `location` should be `location /script`, not `location /new_script`.

Comment: Correct. I made a mistake when anonymising the configuration. Thanks! I edited the line.

Comment: I'm still not confident you have transcripted it correctly. Maybe you should try a real minimal configuration that reproduces the problem and copy/paste it here. I also think that you are confusing the terminology: proxy passing and redirecting are different things.